# Is the IF function removing the date object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement, format

I've spent an hour looking for answers and trying different things so I appreciate any help here.

The following code works great for finding someone's part B effective date. However, when someone's birthday is really on the 1st of a month the 'if' function get's used, and I'm no longer able to format and write the date. It's almost like 'partB_eff' is no longer a date object. (I'm a newbie, so I might just be making this part up.)

I'm getting the error "TypeError: partB_eff.toLocaleDateString is not a function at AutoFill_6_Step_Checklist(Code:24:27)"

How can I resolve this?

```
let birthday = new Date(e.values[2]);
    //this is a date entered from a google form
let bdayCopy = new Date(birthday);
    //I created this since I'll be using .setMonth(), and I don't want to change the original date of the birhtday
let bday65 = new Date(bdayCopy.setMonth(bdayCopy.getMonth()+780));
    //finds the 65th birthday
let partB_eff = new Date(bdayCopy.setDate(01));
    //find's the Medicare part B effective date (the 1st of the month someone turns 65)

if(birthday.getDate()==1){
    partB_eff = partB_eff.getMonth-1;
    //if the person's birthday is really on the 1st of the month, the part b effective date is the 1st of the month prior. partB_eff must be converted
  }

partB_eff = partB_eff.toLocaleDateString('en-us',{year:"numeric",month: "short",day:"numeric"});
    //format partB_eff so that it looks nice on paper
```

Comment: I guess ´partB_eff.getMonth-1´ was not intentional with the missing ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
partB_eff = partB_eff.getMonth-1;
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. What it does is get the vound *function* getDate from your date object, and attempt to subtract one from it. In any other language trying to do subtraction on a function would be a type error, but Javascript is Javascript and allows numeric operations on almost any type. A function minus a number in JS is `NaN`. `NaN` doesn't have a method called `toLocaleString`, hence the error.

What's interesting is that you did the same operation correctly above with `bdayCopy.setMonth(bdayCopy.getMonth()+780)`
Just do the same thing here

```
bdayCopy = new Date(bdayCopy.setMonth(bdayCopy.getMonth()-1));
```

Also some important concepts. `if` in Javascript is *not* a function. `if` is a keyword that starts a conditional statement. You can't do any of the things you can do with a function with if. You can't call it or assign it to a variable or pass ot as a function argument. Clearly understanding what a function is is something you need to do to be able to work in JS, or frankly any other language.

Finally if you are doing date math in JS I strongly recommend you use a date library like DateFns or Moment. Javascript native date APIs are possibly the worst designed date API of any language ever.

Comment: Thank you this worked! I tried bdayCopy = Date(bdayCopy.setMonth(bdayCopy.getMonth()-1)); but didn't put the 'new' in there as I thought it would cause an error that bdayCopy already exists). So close.